# Loop inside function doesn't append content to parent

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, appendchild, setattribute

I am trying to append content to a parent element using a loop inside a function.
I want to append several divs to an element, but (obviously) want the flexibility to change things such as class name, text, etc.
Here is my code:

```
var head = document.getElementById('head');

var someText = "Hello, World";
var someAttributes = [['class', 'blue'], ['id', 'footer'], ['name', 'bunk']];


function createEl(tag, parent)  {
  var newElement = document.createElement(tag);
  return parent.appendChild(newElement);
}

function addText(text, parent) {
  return parent.textContent = text;
}
function addAttribute(attributes, parent) {
  for(var i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
    parent.setAttribute(attributes[i][0], attributes[i][1]);
  }
}

function newEl(parent, element, attr, text) {
  var el = createEl(element, parent);
  addText(text, el);
  addAttribute(attr, el);
  return parent;
}

var derp = newEl(head, 'div', someAttributes, someText);

function loop(num, content) {
  for(var i = 0; i < num; i++)  {
    content;
    console.log('derp');
  }
}

loop(3, derp);
```

I can get it working if I change it to the following:

```
function loop(num, a, b, c, d) {
  for(var i = 0; i < num; i++)  {
    content newEl(a, b, c, d);
    console.log('derp');
  }
}

loop(3, head, 'div', someAttributes, someText);
```

Why it doesn't work with `loop(3, derp)`

Comment: And the quesiton is ...?

Comment: The OP can't use `derp` as an argument to `loop`. @mcnutty, you should edit the question to make this point more clear. Just add a sentence like this: "Why it doesn't work with `loop(3, derp)`?

Answer (score 1):

derp is useless variable which holds `head` (the return value of newEl), make it function and call inside loopo

```
var derp = function(){
  return newEl(head, 'div', someAttributes, someText);
};

function loop(num, content) {
  for(var i = 0; i < num; i++)  {
    content(); // <== call function derp here
    console.log('derp');
  }
}

loop(3, derp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create one function and loop everything within that function. In order to keep track of each element, push them into an array. Remember, ids must be unique, so `addAttribute()` will invalidate your HTML because each element will have the same id. Btw, try to avoid functions within loops, it can get messy.

#### SNIPPET

```js
var base = document.createElement('main');
document.body.appendChild(base);

var tag = "div";
var str = " reporting for duty, sir!";
var att = [['class', 'infantry'], ['name', 'trooper']];
var cnt = 0;
var qty = 3;
var ico = 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/starwars/icons/128/clone-4.png';

function cloneLab(tag, str, att, qty) {

  var unit = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < qty; i++)  {
    var trooper = document.createElement(tag);
    
    unit.push(trooper);
    cnt++;
    unit[i].id = 'trooper'+cnt;
    for(var j = 0; j < att.length; j++) {
      trooper.setAttribute(att[j][0], att[j][1]);
    }
    trooper.textContent = unit[i].id + str;
    trooper.style.backgroundImage = "url("+ico+")";
    base.appendChild(unit[i]);
  }
  return unit;
}

cloneLab(tag, str, att, qty);
```

```css
main { border: 5px inset grey; }
.infantry { border: 1px solid blue; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: contain; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.create(derp);` to build new objects that inherit from `derp`

```js
var head = document.getElementById('head');

var someText = "Hello, World";
var someAttributes = [
  ['class', 'blue'],
  ['id', 'footer'],
  ['name', 'bunk']
];


function createEl(tag, parent) {
  var newElement = document.createElement(tag);
  return parent.appendChild(newElement);
}

function addText(text, parent) {
  return parent.textContent = text;
}

function addAttribute(attributes, parent) {
  for (var i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
    parent.setAttribute(attributes[i][0], attributes[i][1]);
  }
}

function newEl(parent, element, attr, text) {
  var el = createEl(element, parent);
  addText(text, el);
  addAttribute(attr, el);
  return parent;
}

var derp = newEl(head, 'div', someAttributes, someText);



function loop(num, content) {
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    newEl(head, 'div', someAttributes, someText);
    Object.create(derp);
  }
}

loop(3, derp);
```

```css
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="head" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues with the code here.

Firstly you there is no element with the id of 'head' to get as parent. So the js fails right away.

Even if you have an element with the name of 'head', you need to wait till the document loaded.

Either you can use jQuery `document.ready` function or `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { });` if you gonna use pure js. You can copy your code in side these above mentioned functions.

If you follow these steps your code will work perfectly.

PS: Please note that `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { });` may not work with IE.

HOPE THIS WILL HELP YOU.